# Can't arange 2 DIV, or elements inlnie with SVG and modal bootstrap

Tags: svg, modal-dialog, raphael

I use Bootstrap Modal & Raphael JS library to work with SVG map.

I need to put in a modal window 2 divs. The first div contains svg another text only.

Structure of divs is simple:

```
        <div id="data-modal" class="modal hide">

            <div id="map-region"></div>

            <div id="raion-desc">TEXT</div>

        </div>
```

Where **ID** (data-modal, map-region, region-desc) have not any CSS styles, it's used with JS.
[image]

Class **modal** is used for Modal window, with JS